# Why do I get a "error: Bad entry 'en_US '" when generating locales?

Tags: locale, i18n

Code talks louder than words:

```
root@myhost # locale-gen
Generating locales (this might take a while)...
```

(skipping a bit here)

```
error: Bad entry 'en_GB '
  en_GB.UTF-8... done
```

(skipping a bit here)

```
  en_SG.UTF-8... done
error: Bad entry 'en_US '
  en_US.ISO-8859-1... done
  en_US.UTF-8... done
error: Bad entry 'en_US.iso88591 '
error: Bad entry 'en_US.iso885915 '
  en_ZA.UTF-8... done
```

(skipping a bit here)

```
Generation complete.
```

Why am I getting these errors and how can I avoid them?

Notes:

- I use Linux Mint 18.2, but this started happening at some point in the (near?) past with Mint 18.1. They're both based on Ubuntu 16.04 I think.
- I haven't found files with these "bad entries" (with or without the extra space at the end) under `/etc`; specifically not `/etc/locale.gen`.

**Additional info:**

Relevant contents of `/etc/locale.gen`:

```
# grep -v "#" /etc/locale.gen | sed "s/$/+/" | grep "en_"
en_GB.UTF-8 UTF-8+
en_US ISO-8859-1+
en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8+
```

Comment: Is that an extra space after the offending locales?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro: It looks like it, but I haven't found a file in `/etc` with that extra space.

Comment: what is the output of  `grep -v "#" /etc/locale.gen | sed "s/$/+/"`?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro: See edit. I should also mention I had not messed with that file manually.

Comment: That file seems ok *I think*. At least the UTF entries are ok. What happens if you comment the ISO-8859-1 line and run `locale-gen`?

Comment: Debian 9 here. Running something similar to yours, including `en_US ISO-8859-1` does not produce any error.

Comment: Has someone purge locale files to save space?

Comment: This solution worked for me: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/439304/8234

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit: This workaround is probably not the best solution; but it does work.**

Based on @StephaneChazelas' [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/375177/34868), I figured out the problem is with `/var/lib/locales/supported.d/mintlocale` - a file specific to my distribution, Linux Mint. It is mis-generated, without charset fields for most (not all) of the lines, e.g.:

```
en_GB
en_GB.iso88591
en_GB.UTF-8 UTF-8
```

(skipping)

```
en_US
en_US.iso88591
en_US.iso885915
en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8
```

So what I needed to do is generate the second field for everything. Here's what I did, basically:

```
sed -i -r '/^[a-zA-Z_]*$/d' mintlocale
sed -i -r 's/.([^. ]+)$/.\1 \1/' mintlocale
sed -i -r 's/ iso8859([0-9]+)$/ISO-8859-\1/' mintlocale
```

so, removing the lines without a .charset suffix, replicating the .charset suffix after a space, and changing the ISO 8859 charset formatting to match what we have in `/usr/shared/i18n/charmaps/` (otherwise we'd get other errors).

Finally, I re-ran `locale-gen` and no there were no errors.

**Note:** I'm not 100% sure about the removal of the charset-less lines, so comments about that are welcome.

Comment: I'd say you can probably remove that file altogether and use `dpkg-reconfigure locales` instead of `mintlocale`.

Answer (score 4):

`locale-gen` is a (not very well written) `bash` script. That error is reported by:

```
is_entry_ok() {
  if [ -n "$locale" -a -n "$charset" ] ; then
    true
  else
    echo "error: Bad entry '$locale $charset'"
    false
  fi
}
```

So, here the problem is that `$charset` is empty.

The list of locales to generate is compiled from `/etc/locale.gen` and all the files in `/var/lib/locales/supported.d`.

Possibly, one of the files in there contains `en_US` on its own without the name of a charset.

Since your `/etc/locale.gen` doesn't have a `en_SG.UTF-8`, you most probably have files in `/var/lib/locale/supported.d`, and that's probably the ones that have malformed lines. Once you've identified the culprit, you can use `dpkg -S` on its path to see which package it came from if any.

Comment: That should be easy to find out...only if it is in a bad commented line. Interestingly enough, the OP is saying he did not mess *manually* with the offending file.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro, the problem is likely to be in a file in `/var/lib/locales/supported.d` (`language-pack-*` packages at least put files in there). Given the way that script is written, another possibility could be a comment line that contains `# blahblah \nen_US`, but that would be unlikely.

Comment: The culprit is `/var/lib/locales/supported.d/mintlocale`, which is generated - so it seems - by either the mintlocale package or the mint-translations package (probably the first). Perhaps I should post something to the Mint forums then.

Comment: @einpoklum, yes, I can reproduce if I run `mintlocale`, and then click _Install/Remove Languages_ and then _Add..._ and add any language. It then generates the broken `supported.d/mintlocale file`. If you look at `/usr/lib/linuxmint/mintlocale/add.py`, it does a `localedef --list-archive | sed 's/utf8/UTF-8 UTF-8/g' > /var/lib/locales/supported.d/mintlocale` which is the source of the problem.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Please read my answer. You've traced the problem to the source, but for now I have a temporary fix. I should probably amend my answer to suggest a change to that python file.

Comment: @einpoklum That python code makes little sense. `localedef --list-archive` reports the list of already generated locale names. So dumping that (and incorrectly trying to derive the charset from the name) into a file meant to be used as the basis for generating locales makes no sense.