# Arch linux: locale issue

Tags: arch-linux, locale, glibc

After replacing of glibc with glibc-git the system does not have any locales at all.
I've switched back to glibc and it is the same (no locales).
Trying to regen the locales I get:

```
# locale-gen
Generating locales...
error: Bad entry 'C '
error: Bad entry 'POSIX '
error: Bad entry 'de_DE.utf8 '
error: Bad entry 'en_US.utf8 '
Generation complete.
```

System: Arch Linux

glibc: 2.26-11.0

/etc/locale.conf

```
LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE=C
LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_PAPER=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_NAME=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION="de_DE.UTF-8"
```

/etc/locale.gen

```
C
POSIX
de_DE.utf8
en_US.utf8
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have got no locales files installed obviously. Someone else may tell you how to install them, Arch is not my thing.

Comment: The locales in the locale.gen file appear to be defined like this: `de_DE.UTF-8 UTF-8`.  Try putting that in your `/etc/locale.gen` and regenerating.  (unless it has always worked?  I don't know but this is what is on my system)

Comment: @arcsin Thanks! The right syntax for locale.gen is: de_DE.UTF-8 UTF-8
en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8. Problem solved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right syntax for locale.gen is:

```
de_DE.UTF-8 UTF-8 
en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8
```

Problem solved!

Comment: Apparently "cloud-init v. 21.1" generates the wrong locale.gen syntax.  I commented out #LANG="en_blah" and used your syntax and `local-gen` worked, and now I can init postgresql without errors :-/ Very strange!