# error: Bad entry 'en_AG ', etc, when generating locales on Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, locale, language

I am unsure what is happening with those "bad locales", I am updating my laptop regularly once daily. This came up today:

```
Setting up locales (2.35-0ubuntu3.4) ...
Generating locales (this might take a while)...
  cs_CZ.UTF-8... done
error: Bad entry 'en_AG '
  en_AG.UTF-8... done
  en_AG.UTF-8... done
  en_AU.UTF-8... done
  en_BW.UTF-8... done
  en_CA.UTF-8... done
  en_DK.UTF-8... done
  en_GB.UTF-8... done
  en_HK.UTF-8... done
  en_IE.UTF-8... done
error: Bad entry 'en_IL '
  en_IL.UTF-8... done
  en_IL.UTF-8... done
error: Bad entry 'en_IN '
  en_IN.UTF-8... done
  en_IN.UTF-8... done
error: Bad entry 'en_NG '
  en_NG.UTF-8... done
  en_NG.UTF-8... done
  en_NZ.UTF-8... done
  en_PH.UTF-8... done
  en_SG.UTF-8... done
  en_US.UTF-8... done
  en_ZA.UTF-8... done
error: Bad entry 'en_ZM '
  en_ZM.UTF-8... done
  en_ZM.UTF-8... done
  en_ZW.UTF-8... done
  sk_SK.UTF-8... done
Generation complete.
```

---

I found a file where there are these entries listed:

```
$ cat /var/lib/locales/supported.d/en
en_HK.UTF-8 UTF-8
en_DK.UTF-8 UTF-8
en_IN UTF-8
en_IL UTF-8
en_ZM UTF-8
en_ZW.UTF-8 UTF-8
en_NZ.UTF-8 UTF-8
en_PH.UTF-8 UTF-8
en_NG UTF-8
en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8
en_GB.UTF-8 UTF-8
en_AU.UTF-8 UTF-8
en_SG.UTF-8 UTF-8
en_BW.UTF-8 UTF-8
en_AG UTF-8
en_ZA.UTF-8 UTF-8
en_CA.UTF-8 UTF-8
en_IE.UTF-8 UTF-8
```

---

Adding the `UTF-8` keyword where missing and running `sudo locale-gen` does not help, it shows this where the keyword is manually added:

> ```
> ...Try `localedef --help' or `localedef --usage' for more information.
> ```

---

PS: I am on Linux Mint 21.2 (Victoria) Cinnamon and I can edit installed languages here:

[image: installed languages on Linux Mint]

---

Any help is appreciated!

---

Today I tried `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales` without a luck.

Comment: does this help https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/375166 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [don_crissti](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22142/don-crissti)'s comment [leading me to this answer I found value in](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/375303/126755), I now know there is a file specific to my distribution (Linux Mint):

```
/var/lib/locales/supported.d/mintlocale
```

which contained exactly the following:

```
cs_CZ.UTF-8 UTF-8
en_AG
en_AG.UTF-8 UTF-8
en_AU.UTF-8 UTF-8
en_BW.UTF-8 UTF-8
en_CA.UTF-8 UTF-8
en_DK.UTF-8 UTF-8
en_GB.UTF-8 UTF-8
en_HK.UTF-8 UTF-8
en_IE.UTF-8 UTF-8
en_IL
en_IL.UTF-8 UTF-8
en_IN
en_IN.UTF-8 UTF-8
en_NG
en_NG.UTF-8 UTF-8
en_NZ.UTF-8 UTF-8
en_PH.UTF-8 UTF-8
en_SG.UTF-8 UTF-8
en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8
en_ZA.UTF-8 UTF-8
en_ZM
en_ZM.UTF-8 UTF-8
en_ZW.UTF-8 UTF-8
sk_SK.UTF-8 UTF-8
```

Plus, the file that I mentioned in the question `/var/lib/locales/supported.d/en` contained:

```
en_HK.UTF-8 UTF-8
en_DK.UTF-8 UTF-8
en_IN UTF-8
en_IL UTF-8
en_ZM UTF-8
en_ZW.UTF-8 UTF-8
en_NZ.UTF-8 UTF-8
en_PH.UTF-8 UTF-8
en_NG UTF-8
en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8
en_GB.UTF-8 UTF-8
en_AU.UTF-8 UTF-8
en_SG.UTF-8 UTF-8
en_BW.UTF-8 UTF-8
en_AG UTF-8
en_ZA.UTF-8 UTF-8
en_CA.UTF-8 UTF-8
en_IE.UTF-8 UTF-8
```

---

Solution:

1. As you can see for yourself, there are strange lines without any encoding. I commented out these lines in the file above.
2. In the other file, make sure the format is like: `xx_YY.UTF-8 UTF-8` on all lines.

Now I can run `locale-gen` without any trace of error.

Comment: I think the lines like `xx_YY UTF-8` are correct in the “other” file: there’s no requirement to embed the encoding in the locale’s name.

Comment: @user2233709 You may be correct, but since it worked for me that way, it is not against anything I assume. All EN language packs have been preinstalled since the OS installation, which was years ago (I update/upgrade regularly) = 2018-06-16. So I likely assume correctly that _something_ messed up these files. Cheers, and I am not saying you are incorrect. Good luck.